# Deploying with Capistrano from Local Machine to VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, repository, capistrano, vps, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a Rails application from my local machine to the VPS through Capistrano. I've installed Capistrano by including it in the Gemfile and running 'bundle'. Then I ran 'capify .' and added the ff to the Capfile.

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p136@foobar'
```

Now, I'm stuck with the deploy.rb, I'm not sure what values should I put into the file. If I don't host my code in Github or other online repositories, what should I place in the set :repository option? And what exactly is set :domain? Should I use the ip address of my VPS machine here? Btw, I'm following the tutorial from http://infinite-sushi.com/2011/01/deploying-a-rails-app-to-a-linode-box/, and here's the sample deploy.rb.

```
set :user, 'deploy'
set :domain, 'foo.bar.us'
set :application, "my_web_app"

set :repository, "git@github.com:foo/repo.git"  # Your clone URL
set :scm, "git"
set :branch, "master"
set :scm_verbose, true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm_passphrase, "password"  # The deploy user's password
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{domain}"
set :use_sudo, false

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

role :web, domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  domain, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Comment: So is your repository set up locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set :scm, :none
set :deploy_via, :rsync_with_remote_cache
```

You can also try `:deploy_via, :copy`. 
As for the `:domain` option, the example you followed is using that for both naming as well as for accessing the server. I'd suggest just hardcoding the ip addresses with the servers for now. I know it's not DRY, but if your cluster grows in size, you'll want to change these values (or just set the ip to a variable for now -- it doesn't really matter):

```
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
role :web, "1.2.3.4"
role :app, ["1.2.3.5", "1.2.3.6"]
```

Comment: So after setting :scm to :none, can I remove the :repository and the :branch lines? How about the :scm_verbose and :scm_passphrase? Sorry, I'm really a newbie when it comes to deploying.

Comment: yeah, these are just variables that various capistrano tasks use, so feel free to remove them, try out a deployment, and see if anything breaks. If you're not using an scm, you can safely remove the branch and other scm_* variables.

Comment: I've tried using set :scm, :none, but I'm getting this error 'Please specify the repository that houses your application's code, set :repository, 'foo'. So what I tried is to use "set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "~/Sites/#{application}/.git"
set :branch, "master", however I'm still getting this error when running cap deploy:cold "failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p194'"

Comment: That sounds more like an rvm error than a repository error. Is rvm installed with that version of ruby also installed on the production server?

Comment: The ruby versions are the same, but the rvm versions are slightly different. On my local I have rvm 1.14.6 and on the VPS, I have 1.14.12, will it matter?

Comment: I'll mark this as the right answer then, since I'm now having a different problem. Thanks.